# How do I add a custom domain URL to a link sent in the signature completion email request?

Tags: docusignapi

When I upload a document in DocuSign and add a signature field to it and then send it, I have a field called [[Data:QuickURL]] which is populated with appdemo.docusign.com.  I have a valid subdomain (foo.mycompany.com) that is claimed by my DocuSign admin account.  How do I go about getting [[Data:QuickURL]] to point to foo.mycompany.com and not appdemo.docusign.com?

I've added a custom email domain.  I've "claimed" my custom domain and verified that the DNS txt and cname entries are live.

[image: The link that needs changing]

Answer (score 0):

This would likely need to be accomplished using [Email Resource File Branding](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=docusign-email-resource-file-guide&topicId=docusign-email-resource-file-guide.pdf&_LANG=enus&rsc_301). Please note that this is completely self-serve and no support is available for assistance with modifying Resource Files.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to reply.  I did indeed look at the existing resource file and it references `[[Data:QuickURL]]`.  I would like to know where I can make the changes in DocuSign so that that URL shows my custom (claimed) domain.

Comment: In the guide I linked, it shows where you can download the email resource file. You'd need to download that resource file and edit the field in there. If you are not able to see that option, your account may not have that feature enabled.